# Can i use k8s ingress services with external IP without set loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I started working with kubernetes few months ago, i create services and replicaset for differents backends applications.

Now i want use ingress service to access my differents applications from external with my domain name. As it's not in production yet and i use just on node i don't want use loadbalancer.

It is possible to set Service with NodePort and attach it to an Ingress without use loadbalancer?

This is my configuration:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-replicaset-service
  labels:
    app: nginx-demo
spec:
  externalIPs:
    - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  selector:
    app: nginx-replica
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
```

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: www.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: nginx-replicaset-service
              servicePort: 80
    - host: test.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /test
            backend:
              serviceName: other-service
              servicePort: 80
```

When i check the ingress information on my cluster i have the following:

```
NAME         HOSTS                                   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
my-ingress   www.mydomain.com,test.mydomain.com                80      4d22h
```

Address always empty

Answer (score 2):

If your cluster is running on GCP or GKE you can

1) create a global IP address

```
gcloud compute addresses create ingress-static-ip --global
```

2) set the **kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name** annotation on the Ingress config

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ingress-static-ip
  labels:
    app: nginx-replica
```

3) And a service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-replicaset-service
  labels:
    app: nginx-demo
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-replica
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
```

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip

Comment: GKE still creating load balancer even using this configuration

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, or at least it would be awkward. NodePort services are limited to a range of high ports for security reasons so this would require `http://externalip:43210` or whatever port it picked. The more common way to not use a LoadBalancer is to deploy the ingress controller using a DaemonSet and hostNetwork mode so it can listen on 80 and 443. This still leaves the issue of getting the IP(s) to a user though. For development purposes, you can just pick any of the IPs for your nodes and use that. For prod, it's harder which is why it's not generally recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you shouldn't specify **NodePort** with **ExternalIPs**.
With **ExternalIPs**, you can specify a port directly like this :

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-replicaset-service
  labels:
    app: nginx-demo
spec:
  externalIPs:
    - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  selector:
    app: nginx-replica
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
```

It will mean that you can access the service with **XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80**

It is a normal thing that you don't see any address when describing your ingress, ingress will only contains what you specified in the ingress.yaml : you only used the hostnames in your ingress.

If you do a *"kubectl get svc"* you will see your service with the externalIPs.

Also for your ingress to work it means **www.domain.com** and **test.domain.com** need to point to **XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX**.